# imputation of missing values rowise with perhaps a conditional statement

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

i have this data;

```
       country country.code  gdp00  gdp04   gdp08   gdp12   gdp16   gdp20
1 Afghanistan          AFG     NA   5285   10191   20537   19469   20116
2     Algeria          DZA  54790  85325  171001  209059  159049  145009
3   Argentina          ARG 284204 164658  361558  545982  554861  389288
4     Armenia          ARM   1912   3577   11662   10619   10546      NA
5   Australia          AUS 415034 611904 1052585 1543411 1208039 1327836
6     Austria          AUT 196800 300904  430294  409425      NA  433258
```

where I have missing values for some country's GDP for years gdp00, gdp16 or gdp20.
I want to impute the missing values based on the other years of gdp values for each country.

I have tried:

```
impute <- mice(df[,3:8], m=3, seed = 123)
newDATA <- complete(impute, 1)
```

although For example for Afganistan gdp00 it imputes a value of 11539 which is very high.

Is there a way to get more realistic values using mice package or any new suggestions.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using linear interpolation to impute.  Because there is an ordering by year and you expect smooth trends, interpolation makes sense.  Take a look at the `approx` documentation for `rule = 2`, which can fill values both at the end and the middle of a vector.

I also recommend performing this in long format.  Most of the time, long format data is better for calculations :)  You can `pivot_wider` as a final step if you want the final format in wide.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~country,     ~country.code,  ~gdp00,  ~gdp04,   ~gdp08,   ~gdp12,   ~gdp16,   ~gdp20,
   "Argentina", "ARG",           284204, 164658,  361558,  545982,  554861,  389288,
     "Armenia", "ARM",           1912,   3577,   11662,   10619,   10546,      NA,
     "Austria", "AUT",           196800, 300904,  430294,  409425,      NA,  433258
)

df_long <- df |> 
  pivot_longer(contains("gdp")) |> 
  mutate(
    yr = parse_number(name), 
    value0 = value
  ) |> 
  group_by(country) |> 
  mutate(value = approx(yr, value, yr, rule = 2)$y) |> 
  ungroup()

df_long
#> # A tibble: 18 × 6
#>    country   country.code name    value    yr value0
#>    <chr>     <chr>        <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 Argentina ARG          gdp00 284204      0 284204
#>  2 Argentina ARG          gdp04 164658      4 164658
#>  3 Argentina ARG          gdp08 361558      8 361558
#>  4 Argentina ARG          gdp12 545982     12 545982
#>  5 Argentina ARG          gdp16 554861     16 554861
#>  6 Argentina ARG          gdp20 389288     20 389288
#>  7 Armenia   ARM          gdp00   1912      0   1912
#>  8 Armenia   ARM          gdp04   3577      4   3577
#>  9 Armenia   ARM          gdp08  11662      8  11662
#> 10 Armenia   ARM          gdp12  10619     12  10619
#> 11 Armenia   ARM          gdp16  10546     16  10546
#> 12 Armenia   ARM          gdp20  10546     20     NA
#> 13 Austria   AUT          gdp00 196800      0 196800
#> 14 Austria   AUT          gdp04 300904      4 300904
#> 15 Austria   AUT          gdp08 430294      8 430294
#> 16 Austria   AUT          gdp12 409425     12 409425
#> 17 Austria   AUT          gdp16 421342.    16     NA
#> 18 Austria   AUT          gdp20 433258     20 433258

df_long |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = country:country.code)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 8
#>   country   country.code  gdp00  gdp04  gdp08  gdp12   gdp16  gdp20
#>   <chr>     <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Argentina ARG          284204 164658 361558 545982 554861  389288
#> 2 Armenia   ARM            1912   3577  11662  10619  10546   10546
#> 3 Austria   AUT          196800 300904 430294 409425 421342. 433258
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>